# Proof that the coefficients of formal power series must match

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Say I have $f(z) = \sum_n^\infty a_n z^n$ and $g(z)= \sum_n^\infty b_n z^n$. Now suppose that
$$f(z)=g(z)$$ for infinitely many $z$ that are not discrete. Why is it true that we can match the coefficients of the power series? I have seen answers say because we can write

$$\sum_n^\infty (a_n - b_n) z^n = 0$$

and then match coefficients with the zero power series, however, this is already using the answer to my question, which is why can we match the coefficients of formal power series (including matching coefficients with the zero power series)?

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem?

Comment: By "that are not discrete" do you mean "that have an accumulation point in the open disk where the series converge"?

Comment: If they are *formal* power series then this is true by definition.  So you must be thinking of power series as the limits of the partial sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assume that $0$ is an accumulation point. Since power series are continuous, this gives us $f(0)=g(0)$, so $a_0=b_0$. But then we can consider $f_1(z):=f(z)-f(0)$ and $g_1(z):=g(z)-g(0)$. Their power series expansions are $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k$ and the same with $b_k$, respectively. We can now write $f_1(z)=z\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^{k-1}$ and $g_1(z)=z\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k z^{k-1}$. The two power series in this equation must be equal at the exact same points (except possibly at $0$) as the original ones of $f$ and $g$, so we can apply the same argument to obtain $a_1=b_1$. Repeat inductively to obtain $a_k=b_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Now if $0$ isn't actually an accumulation point, we have to do some more work. I suggest you try drawing the discs I mention on paper. Let $U_R(0)$ be the disc of convergence (and $R$ the radius of convergence). Somewhere in this disc (*not* on its boundary, which you should probably state more clearly instead of just saying that the set is not discrete, because otherwise this doesn't work), there is an accumulation point $z_0$ of the set where $f=g$. We take this point and expand $f$ and $g$ around this point $z_0$. We will get two *different* power series for $f$ and $g$, with new coefficients. But to these two new power series we can apply the argument from above, so their coefficients are equal. We also know that their disc of convergence is at least $U_{r_0}(z_0)$, where $r_0$ the largest possible radius such that $U_{r_0}(z_0)\subseteq U_R(0)$. On this disc, the power series expansions of $f$ and $g$ are equal, so $f$ and $g$ are equal. So every boundary point of this disc $U_{r_0}(z_0)$ is an accumulation point of the set where $f=g$. And apart from the single shared boundary point with $U_R(0)$, they are also contained in $U_R(0)$. Now choose the boundary point of $U_{r_0}(z_0)$ which is closest to $0$. Call it $z_1$. Around this point we can also expand $f$ and $g$ as power series, again with a disc of convergence that is the largest possible one such that it is still contained in $U_R(0)$ (or larger). Its radius, let's call it $r_1$, will be twice that of $U_{r_0}(z_0)$. And on this disc, the functions are again equal, so its boundary points are again accumulation points of the set where $f=g$. Repeat the argument until $0$ is contained in the disc (which happens after a finite number of steps). See Maths Wizzard's excelent visualization below. At this point $0$ must be an accumulation point of the set where $f=g$, so we can finally apply our original argument to the power series.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Just a quick question - in your second paragraph after the sentence where you say that by the same argument as before the coefficients will be equal  you seem to start a new argument "But then they are equal... and the raids of convergence grows with each step". Could you clarify what you are trying to prove/explain/justify with this?

Comment: What if the accumulation point is on the boundary of the disk where the series converge?
For example, try $f(z) = \sin(1/(z-1))$ which is analytic in $|z|< 1$.  Its zeros have an accumulation point $1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I assume that the accumulation point is inside the disc. It's not directly stated in the question, but it is the standard premise for this theorem (and a necessary one, which is what you're getting at, right?)

Comment: @MathsWizzard: I changed my explanation to be more thorough. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thank you very much for the clarification, I think I understand now. You are basically extending the equality of $f=g$ to the origin and then you are using the aforementioned argument. I made a diagram for people looking at your answer https://imgur.com/a/1l2w8Tt . A quick question, could we have said alternatively - since $f$ and $g$ are convergent on $U_{|z_0|} (0)$ then $f$ and $g$ are analytic. The analyticity implies that we have a convergent power series about every point. Write $f=\sum a_n (z-z_0)^n$ and $g=\sum b_n (z-z_0)^n$. Since the complex derivative exists we

Comment: can differentiate and match coefficients for when $z_0$. This can be done inductively to get that the two power series are the same. Is there an error in this argument?

Comment: That visualization is excellent. I've added it to my answer. As for your alternative approach, I see the issue that just because $f=g$ in a point, we don't necessarily have $f'=g'$. Though I wouldn't be surprised to see some argument which allows us to assume that fact, since in the end it does turn out to be true by using the fact we want to prove in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomia $z^n$ are a basis of the vectorial space of polynomia, so if two vectors are equal, they have the same coefficients in any basis.

A different way of understand it is using derivatives. Evaluating any polynomius at $z=0$, it is obvious that if $f(z)=g(z)\Rightarrow f(0)=g(0) \Rightarrow a_0=b_0$. You also can do it taking derivatives!

$\left.\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\right|_{z=0}f(z)=\left.\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\right|_{z=0}g(z)$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\left.\frac{d^kz^n}{dz^k}\right|_{z=0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\left.\frac{d^kz^n}{dz^k}\right|_{z=0}$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n k!\delta_{k,n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n k!\delta_{k,n}$

$k! a_k=k! b_k\Leftrightarrow a_k=b_k$

Where we introduced the Kroneker delta $\delta_{k,n}=\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}1 &k=m\\0&k\neq m\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: We're in the vector space of power series, though, not that of polynomials. The monomials are not a (Hamel) basis of this space. Also, the assumption is only that the points where $f=g$ have an accumulation point, not that $f=g$ everywhere.